# Parsing Content With Beautiful Soup Between Two Closing Tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse the contents of a webpage with Artist and Album info. I have parsed the information down to this:

```
`<span dir="ltr"><a href="unique?id=1234">Jay-Z</a> &amp; <a href="unique?id" = 321">Kanye West</a> - Watch the Throne</span>`
```

The album name (in this case "Watch the Throne") is always before the closing `</span>` tag.

I need to parse the album data out of the whole `<span>` element no matter how many artists are included on the album, be it a singular artist or 30 artists.

The difficulty lies in fact that the album name is between two closing tag elements.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<span dir="ltr"><a href="unique?id=1234">Jay-Z</a> &amp; 
... <a href="unique?id" = 321">Kanye West</a> - Watch the Throne</span>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.span.contents[-1].strip('- ')
u'Watch the Throne'
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it. Thank you so much. BeautifulSoup is an amazing tool. Its almost too simple. I just overcomplicate my approach.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly, the album name will always be at the end of the span element. You could try to find the last index of the closing of the a-tag, and the last index of the closing of the span-tag and from that build a string containing the album information.

So, using `theString.rfind("</a>")` you will find the starting index and `theString.rfind("</span>")` to find the closing index.

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed. I'm fairly new to python and was so focused on getting BeautifulSoup to do the dirty work I forgot about being able to find the range in a string. Thanks!

Comment: but you don't really need this - you could use native BeautifulSoup to solve this - would be shorter and more elegant I believe

Comment: Yeah you are right. BeautifulSoup could do this in a snap. A person below you cleared it right up with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if s is the soup element then:

```
album = s.findAll('a')[-1].nextSibling
```

I guess you can clean the " - " by yourself
good luck, I love beautifulsoup